# How to use expect with optional prompts?

Tags: linux, bash, expect

Let's say I am trying to write an expect script for a test.sh that has three prompts: prompt1, prompt2, prompt3.

My code is like this:

```sh
spawn test.sh
expect "prompt1"
send "pass1"
expect "prompt2"
send "pass2"
expect "prompt3"
send "pass3"
```

However, prompt2 only occurs half the time. If prompt2 doesn't show up, the expect script breaks. How would I write expect code that skips over prompt2 if it doesn't show up?

EDIT:

Fixed my code:

```sh
/usr/bin/expect -c '
spawn ./test.sh
expect {
      "prompt1" {
          send "pass1\r"
          exp_continue
      }
      "prompt2" {
          send "pass2\r"
          exp_continue
      }
      "prompt3" {
          send "pass3\r"
          exp_continue
      }
}
interact return
'
```

This way, the rest of the script executes and provides output.

Comment: You will need to `expect` another pattern to be able to break out of the loop. Otherwise you'll never get to the `interact` line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can expect multiple things:

```
expect { 
    "prompt2" { 
        send "pass2"
        expect "prompt3"
        send "pass3"
    }
    "prompt3" {
        send "pass3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh man, didn't see this but this is near identical to my fix.

Comment: How would one avoid the `prompt3`/`pass3` code duplication?

Answer (score 26):

As long as you have a case that will be always be expected to hit and don't include an `exp_continue` in that case, you can can remove duplication and handle optional prompts easily:

```
expect "prompt1"
send "pass1"
expect { 
    "prompt2" { 
        send "pass2"
        exp_continue
    }
    "prompt3" {
        send "pass3"
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already upvoted the accepted answer but this one is much more elegant (Don't Repeat Yourself); `exp_continue` works well to solve the optional prompt problem.

Comment: This one is neat.